# Jquery generate Id inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

How is it possible to generate ids in a loop,
current I have something like this but did not work:

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++)
$("#input-themen-word'+i+'").fileinput({
....
});
```

In the end it should generate ids like:

#input-themen-word1

#input-themen-word2

#input-themen-word3

#input-themen-word4

#input-themen-word5
....

Comment: i think you are looking for `$("#input-themen-word"+i).`

Comment: You might be better off using a single selector instead of a loop: `$('[id^=input-themen-word]')`. This selects all elements whose ID starts with `input-themen-word`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(("#input-themen-word" + i)).fileinput({
```

You were trying to mix and match `'` with `"`...